# How to sort rows with pandas based on name non-alphabetically

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sorting, alphabetical

My company has tasked me with a basic programming problem (I am new to Python).

If I have an array in an excel file with the following layout:

```
Panel Value
Left  70
Right 50
Top   30
```

Since the code generates csv files in sorts the columns in alphabetical order; I want it to write to an excel as:

```
Panel Value
Left  70
Top   30
Right 50
```

The code I have so far sort a csv file is:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
import xlrd

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')
df.sort_values(["Panel","Value"], axis=0, 
                 ascending=[True,False], inplace=True) 
df.to_csv('Output2.csv')
print(df)
```

Comment: Whats the logic of your new sort?

Comment: All the code is doing is taking an excel file and alphabetizing it. However when you alphabetize it sorts it Left,Right,Top. I want code that sorts it Left, Top, Right

Comment: I understood that part, but normally theres a "logic" to sorting, in this case "lexicographic" or also known as "alphabetic". So what I understand is your new sort has no logic, just hardcode your sort.

Comment: so what happens when you have `left, top, right` and `down`? where would that be sorted?

Comment: - Erfan, yeah im not sure how to do that

Answer (score 4):

From the comments I understand that you want to do a "manual" sort. So in this case we have to hardcore it by passing a list to [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Panel').reindex(['Left', 'Top', 'Right']).reset_index()

   Panel  Value
0   Left     70
1    Top     30
2  Right     50
```

**Fully working example**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Panel':['Left', 'Right', 'Top'],
                   'Value':[70, 50, 30]})
print(df, '\n')


df = df.set_index('Panel').reindex(['Left', 'Top', 'Right']).reset_index()
print(df)
```

```
   Panel  Value
0   Left     70
1  Right     50
2    Top     30 

   Panel  Value
0   Left     70
1    Top     30
2  Right     50

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: When I input that line it got rid of the values in the Value column

Comment: That does not make sense. Can you copy and paste my `Fully working example` code and see if that works. @Newtopy91

Answer (score 3):

you can also use **[`pd.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html)** here with `ordered=True` to sort according to categories order:

```
df['Panel'] = pd.Categorical(df['Panel'],categories=['Left','Top','Right'],ordered=True)
final = df.sort_values('Panel')
```

---

```
   Panel  Value
0   Left     70
2    Top     30
1  Right     50
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for your given requirement.

```
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')

data=[]
data.append([df['Panel'][0],df['Value'][0]])
data.append([df['Panel'][2],df['Value'][2]])
data.append([df['Panel'][1],df['Value'][1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Panel', 'Value'])
df.to_csv('Output2.csv',index=False)
```

I am assuming that the input file have always the order : Left, Right, Top.

or simply,

```
df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')
df = df.set_index('Panel').reindex(['Left', 'Top', 'Right'])
df.to_csv('Output2.csv')
```